# Placeholder text is editable

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, placeholder

My form behaves strangely.  Other forms in our system behave just fine, but mine does some subtly weird things in IE11. It seems to be because some of the components aren't cohabiting nicely.

My question is: how do I stop it doing these weird things and why are these weird things happening?

My form displays a list of property sales in a `<table>`.  Each sale has its own `<tbody>` with a few `<tr>`s within it.  One of the cells contains a file input which has a tooltip (from Bootstrap).  I have to hide some of the sales when the form is first displayed, which I do using `display: none` or JQuery `.hide()`.  The form also uses placeholders and some "mandatory input decoration" (automatically putting an asterisk beside mandatory inputs) based on code from [here](http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/2012/11/indicating-required-fields-with-twitter-bootstrap-and-aspnet-mvc-4#.VyapK_l96Ul).

By a process of elimination, I've found two things that can stop the weird things from happening: not hiding any of the `<tr>`s containing the file inputs, and not using any mandatory input decoration.  Unfortunately I need to do both of these things.

**Weird things**

1. **Initial caret placement**: in the initially focussed text box (the address field, which is pre-populated), the caret sometimes appears at the start of the text, sometimes at the end
2. **Editable placeholder**: see below
3. **Tab title**: the browser tab text gets stuck at "Waiting for ..."
4. **Weird patterns of weird behaviour**: see below

**Editable placeholder**

When I click a textbox with a placeholder, normal behaviour is for the caret to appear at the left hand side of the textbox with (in Chrome) placeholder text still visible to the right of the caret, or (in IE11) the placeholder text gone.  But when my page is behaving weirdly in IE11, the caret appears after the placeholder:

[image: comment box with caret after placeholder]

... and is editable ...

[image: comment box with modified placeholder]

When the form is submitted, any updated placeholder content is not submitted with it, so there's a chance my users could enter text which they think will be saved, but isn't.

The placeholder weirdness is delicate too: it only happens for the first mouse click on the page; things behave normally with subsequent clicks or keyboard tabbing between fields.

**Weird patterns of weird behaviour**

*Things work differently depending on what happened before the page was displayed.*

On the first display, placeholders are editable.  If I click into a placeholder (i.e. get the caret to appear somewhere in or after the placeholder text), the page behaves differently after refresh than if I didn't click into a placeholder.

If I first click into one of the textboxes with a placeholder and the placeholder is editable, then after F5 the initially focussed text box will have the caret at the start.  Or, if the initially focussed textbox *had* the caret at the start to begin with, and I don't do anything with the form, the caret goes to the start again after F5.  If the initially focussed textbox had the caret at the end, then I can edit the placeholder text of my comment field...  It's a bit confusing.

**What I've tried**

We normally use [this](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) to make placeholders work in older browsers.  I've tried removing it but that makes no difference.

I tried [this script](https://gist.github.com/hagenburger/379601), but it just makes the problem slightly different: the caret moves to the start of the placeholder, but it's still editable.

I've tried removing `nicefileinput`, but that made no difference.

Here's my entire form.  The "Comment" field appears about half way down the form

```
@model OurCompany.Web.ViewModels.OurProductCompleteDesktopSalesComparisonViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CompleteDesktopSalesComparison";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/content/css/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Scripts/DICurrencyInputFormatter.js"></script>

<section class="container-wrap">
<div class="container">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/OurProduct/_CompleteHeaderPartial.cshtml")
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CompleteDesktopSalesComparison", "OurProduct", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Valuation.OrderNumber)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property.DIPID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property.FullAddress)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Valuation.CategoryCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Valuation.ValuationTypeCode)

        @Html.Partial("~/Views/OurProduct/_CompleteNavigationTabsPartial.cshtml")

        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
            <div>
                @*Sales comparisons==============================================================================*@
                @Html.Hidden("saleCount", Model.ComparableSales.Count)
                <table class="table table-default">
                    @foreach (var sale in Model.ComparableSales)
                    {
                        var saleIndex = Model.ComparableSales.IndexOf(sale);
                        var isVisible = sale.Visible;

                        var shadedClass = saleIndex % 2 == 0 ? string.Empty : "shaded-rows";
                        var visibleStyle = isVisible ? string.Empty : "display: none;";
                        var saleTbodyId = string.Format("saleTbody{0}", saleIndex);
                        var selectedId = string.Format("selected{0}", saleIndex);
                        var visibleId = string.Format("visible{0}", saleIndex);

                        <tbody id="@saleTbodyId" class="@shadedClass" style="@visibleStyle">
                        @*Address, selected*@
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Sequence)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Visible, new{ id = visibleId})
                                Address
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].FullAddress, new {@class = "form-control tt-query", style = "width: 100%;", placeholder = "Full address of sale"})
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].FullAddress)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Dipid)
                                <script>
                                    $("#Valuation_ComparableSales_@(saleIndex)__FullAddress").on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", function(e, datum) {
                                        $("#Valuation_ComparableSales_@(saleIndex)__Dipid").val(datum.SearchKey);
                                    })
                                </script>
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Selected)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Selected, new { id = selectedId })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @*Date, Price*@
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Date)</td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="di-mandatory-field-container di-mandatory-field-text" style="position: relative;">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Date,
                                        Model.GetSalesDateListInstance(Model.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Date),
                                        new { @class = "form-control" })
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].PriceString)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].PriceString,
                                    new { @class = "form-control currency-0-decimals", placeholder = "Sale price" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].PriceString)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Price)
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        @*Floor Area, Bedrooms*@
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].FloorArea)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].FloorArea,
                                    new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Floor Area" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].FloorArea)
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Bedrooms)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Bedrooms,
                                    new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Bedrooms" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Bedrooms)
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        @*Land Area, Bathrooms*@
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].LandArea)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].LandArea,
                                    new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Land Area" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].LandArea)
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Bathrooms)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Bathrooms,
                                    new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Bathrooms" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Bathrooms)
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        @*Comment*@
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Comment)</td>
                            <td colspan="5">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Comment,
                                    new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Comments" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Comment)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @*Image*@
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>Image</p>
                                <p>(@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FileExtensionConstraintMessages["VALUATION_REPORT_SALE_IMAGE"]))</p>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="5">
                                @if (Model.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Images != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (var file in Model.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Images)
                                    {
                                        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(f => file.FileName) (Created: @Html.DisplayFor(f => file.CreateDate))</span>
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("PropertyFile", "Files", new { orderNumber = Model.Valuation.OrderNumber, fileTypeCode = file.FileTypeCode, userFileId = file.Id })"><i class="fa fa-file fa-lg"></i></a>
                                        <br/>
                                    }
                                }
                                <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FileUploadConstraintMessages["VALUATION_REPORT_SALE_IMAGE"])">
                                    <input type="file" name="sale@(saleIndex)Image"/>
                                </span>
                                @{ var validationMessageKey = String.Format("SaleComparisonImage{0}", saleIndex); }
                                @Html.ValidationMessage(validationMessageKey)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @*Comparability*@
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Comparability)</td>
                            <td colspan="5">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Comparability,
                                    new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Comparability - e.g. Inferior, Comparable, Superior" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ComparableSales[saleIndex].Comparability)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    }
                </table>

            </div>
            <div><input id="addSaleButton" type="button" value="Add a sale" class="btn btn-light" /></div>
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("~/Views/OurProduct/_CompleteNavigationButtonsPartial.cshtml")
    }
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="push"></div>
</section>
<script src="~/Content/scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/content/scripts/jquery.nicefileinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/content/scripts/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="~/content/scripts/typeahead.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#addSaleButton").click(function() {
        var saleCount = $("#saleCount").val();
        for (var i = 0; i < saleCount; i++) {
            var saleTbodyId = "saleTbody" + i;
            if ($("#" + saleTbodyId + ":hidden").length > 0) {

                // make the sale visible
                $("#" + saleTbodyId).show();

                // check the Selected checkbox
                var selectedId = "selected" + i;
                $("#" + selectedId).prop("checked", true);

                // set the hidden value to ensure it shows after validation errors
                var visibleId = "visible" + i;
                $("#" + visibleId).val("True");

                // done one, don't do any more
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    $(".tt-query").typeahead({
        name: 'SearchValue',
        valueKey: 'SearchValue',
        limit: 20,
        remote: {
            url: '/properties/GetAddressSearchValues?partSearchValue=%QUERY'
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // tooltips
        $("span").tooltip({ placement: 'top' });

        // custom styling for file input
        $("input[type=file]").nicefileinput();

        // placeholder attribute for old browsers
        $('input, textarea').placeholder();

        $("#ComparableSales_0__FullAddress").focus();
    });

</script>
```

Here's the Mandatory Input Decoration .js file

```
// Add a CSS class to mandatory text input fields.

// see http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/2012/11/indicating-required-fields-with-twitter-bootstrap-and-aspnet-mvc-4#.VMqY0miUfeo
function markRequired() {
    // look at every mandatory field
    $('input[data-val-required]').each(function () {

        // not all should be treated
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("input-append") && !(this).hasAttribute("readonly")) {
            if ($(this).is("input:text")) {
                $(this).wrap("<div class='di-mandatory-field-container di-mandatory-field-text'>");

                //$(this).wrap("<div class='input-group'>");
                //$(this).after("<span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-asterisk required-asterisk'></i></span>");
                //$(this).addClass("di-mandatory-field-container");
                //$(this).addClass("di-mandatory-field-text");
                //$(this).wrap("<span>");
            }
        }
    });
}

function addFootnote() {
    var parentForm;

    // check the form for mandatory class (may be manually- or automatically-added)
    var firstMandatory = $('.di-mandatory-field-container').first();

    // find the form containing that element
    if (firstMandatory != null) {
        var parentFinder = firstMandatory[0];
        while (parentForm == null && parentFinder != null) {
            if (parentFinder.tagName.toLowerCase() == "form") {
                parentForm = parentFinder;
            }
            parentFinder = parentFinder.parentNode;
        }
    }

    // add the footnote
    if (parentForm != null) {
        var rubric = $('<span>', { text: "denotes a mandatory field", style: "position: absolute;" })
            .addClass("di-mandatory-field-footnote");
        rubric.appendTo($(parentForm).parent());
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    markRequired();
    addFootnote();
});
```

Comment: We found this same crazy issue with PrimeFaces.  it must just be some insane IE bug that will never get fixed: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only half an answer (still no idea why the weirdness happens), but somebody might find this helps...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ComparableSales_0__FullAddress").focus();
    $("#selected0").focus();
});
```

Because of the stated "delicate" nature of the bug, it can be killed simply by focussing twice.